# infinite loop while counting dates

Tags: c++, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to solve problem that asks to find how many times 13th day occurs at each weekday in period of 1990+N-1 years.

```
int weekDay = 1;
int week[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

N = 20;

for (int year = 1990; year <= 1990+N-1; year++){
    for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++){
        int days = numberOfDays(year,month);

        for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++){
            if (day == 13)
                week[weekDay] += 1;

            weekDay += 1;
            if (weekDay > 7)
                weekDay = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my solution, however I get stuck in an infinite loop in year and can't seem to fix it.

EDIT : numberOfDays function.

```
int numberOfDays(int year, int month)
{
    if (month == 2 && leapYear(year))
        return 29;
    else if (month == 2)
        return 28;

    if (month == 9 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 11)
        return 30;

    return 31;
}
```

Comment: Could you also post numberOfDays function? If it changes year, or N, it could be explanation.

Comment: What makes you think your issue is in the 'year' loop and not the others? ... I'd guess it was something to do with your numberOfDays() function.

Comment: prefer pre-increment over post-increment and constructor initialization over assignment otherwise Paul covered one of your problems. Arrays start at index 0. `int week[7];` has `week[0]` through `week[6]` elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using weekdays in the range 1..7 but your histogram array `week[]` is indexed 0..6.

---

One possible solution - change:

```
            week[weekDay] += 1;
```

to:

```
            week[weekDay - 1] += 1;
```

---

Another solution - make `week[]` one element bigger and don't use element 0, i.e. change:

```
int week[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

to:

```
int week[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

---

A third possible solution - use week days in the range 0..6, i.e. change:

```
int weekDay = 1;
```

to:

```
int weekDay = 0;
```

and change:

```
        if (weekDay > 7)
            weekDay = 1;
```

to:

```
        if (weekDay > 6)
            weekDay = 0;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Off-by-one. Your `week[]` array has 7 elements, indexed 0..6. You write to `week[7]`, which overwrites something you didn't intend, such as e.g. the `year` variable.